# Table sorting from multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

i'm using jquery and the jquery plugin "tablesorter" (http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to sort a table.
now I have the difficult, that I have following html (an other way is impossible):

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Age</th>
   </tr>    
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Bob</td>
       <td>24</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>James</td>
       <td>33</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>PJ</td>
       <td>28</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Sue</td>
       <td>39</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In every table is one line. Now I want to sort this many tables as it is one table.
Is there any solution for this problem?

I've found an attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8cg4f/31/ 
But there are ony two tables and the script only sort the data from one table.

Comment: Sorry, I used the submit form for the first time...

Answer (score 1):

Target the tables you want to pillage, drill down to the `<tr>`s, move them to where they need to be, climb back up to the (now empty) `<table>`s, throw them away. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGNEr/5/)

```
$('table:not(.tablesorter)').find('tr').appendTo('.tablesorter')
    .end().end().remove();
```

**EDIT:** as per comment I have simulated "spacing between `<tr>`s" by using padding on the `<td>`s [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGNEr/14/).

If you have other requirements for the final page, just let me know what you'd like to end up with and I can help create a solution that will yield valid html which displays consistently for all your users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this isn't the solution. :/ Because of some css styling (I want padding between each <tr>s) I must change the position of the <table>s not of the <tr>s. You know what I mean?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not allowed either, these is no such thing as "spacing between <tr>s". No table elements (except the table itself) can have margins at all. You can however simulate this by placing padding in the <td>s. Adding padding to the top and bottom of all <td>s is functionally equivalent to placing spacing between the <tr>s. If you let us know what your desired outcome is, we might be able to offer a solution instead of frustrating your attempts to create invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var $table = $(".tablesorter");
$table.nextAll("table").children().appendTo($table).end().remove();
$table.tablesorter();
```

Comment: Try to avoid iteration unless your actions depend on the target. If there's no logic to be evaluated, there's no reason to do the work on a case-by-case basis.